# JTable - drag column to increase width

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I am new to Java and I am building a tool which uses a `JTable`. I wanted to expand the column and shrink accordingly, as the user drags the column. I am not exactly sure about the term used for this. This behavior could be noticed in Windows Explorer as attached. How could this be achieved? Proper direction would be appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Resizable columns is default behavior of `JTable`, is it not? Did I misunderstand the question? Can you elaborate what exact functionality you are missing?

Comment: See the `setAutoResizeMode(...)` method of the JTable for different sizing options.

Answer (score 0):

JTable has the setAutoResizeMode, to resize all columns you can use AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS.

```
myTable.setAutoResizeMode(javax.swing.JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
```